# How to generate kubeadm token for secondary control plane node(s)

Tags: kubernetes, token, kubectl

When we launch a master prime node the node creates tokens for worker and master nodes with a ttl.

According to documentation [kubeadm token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/#cmd-token-generate) (I also have tested and it works) we can issue a command and get a new token (with default ttl 24h):

```sh
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

I am trying to figure out if I want to add a new plane node (secondary master) how can I create a relevant token?

I tried passing some flags e.g.:

```sh
kubeadm token create --print-join-command --control-plane
```

but it fails (of course) since this flag is not recognized.

I found also through the documentation that we can do it with a direct link to config file e.g. ref [kubeadm-join/file or https based discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/#file-or-https-based-discovery):

```sh
kubeadm join --discovery-file path/to/file.conf # (local file)
kubeadm join --discovery-file https://url/file.conf # (remote HTTPS URL)
```

In my case I do not have a local conf file or planning to use a url link.

Is there any other way to create a new token using a command for plane nodes and not worker nodes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to run on master

```
kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs
```

Remember the output.

Then you need to run on master

```
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

Then compose joining command for joinning-master-node from this output and add to it `--control-plane --certificate-key xxxx`

See this video to explain with example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27v36t-3afQ
The most interesting is from 20:40.
There are some 'experimental' words in video due to older version.

Comment: Very interesting. I might use this approach when I am updating the CAs in my cluster. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 11):

The following will create the join command for your additional controllers.

```
echo $(kubeadm token create --print-join-command) --control-plane --certificate-key $(kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs | grep -vw -e certificate -e Namespace)
```

Comment: Worked well for me. The single quote at the end should be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments of the users it seems that when someone runs this command:

```sh
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

Should populate two strings sample:

```sh
kubeadm join loadBalancerIP:6443 --token xxxx --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx
kubeadm join loadBalancerIP:6443 --token xxxx --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx --control-plane --certificate-key xxxx
```

In my case unfortunately it did not. Maybe because I am using self signed certs from kubeadm or maybe because the deployment is on bare metal nodes.

Never the less I managed to resolve my problem with a different way.

According to the official documentation [Steps for the first control plane node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/#steps-for-the-first-control-plane-node):

*"You can also specify a custom --certificate-key during init that can later be used by join. To generate such a key you can use the following command:"*

```sh
kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key
```

Once the user runs the command on indented master prime node (not started node yet) it should see something like that:

```sh
# kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key
xxxx
```

Then as the documentation says:

*"Note: The kubeadm init flags --config and --certificate-key cannot be mixed, therefore if you want to use the kubeadm configuration you must add the certificateKey field in the appropriate config locations (under InitConfiguration and JoinConfiguration: controlPlane)."*

In my case I use a conf file so I add the content into my file:

```sh
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
certificateKey: xxxx
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress:
  bindPort: 6443
---
apiServer:
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
---
etc etc
```

Once the user has this key and launches the prime master with this key (as shown above), the next step is to use exactly the same cert key for the secondary master nodes e.g.:

```sh
kubeadm join loadBalancerIP:6443 --token xxxx --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx --control-plane --certificate-key xxxx
```

**Note:** It is recommended to use a script to produce this data in order to use a new cert key when you destroy / create the master node(s).

Hope this helps someone else on the future in order not to spend so much as I did.

Comment: Hey, the output from `kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key` is the same as the expected value after the SHA256 in `--discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx`? If not, do you know how to get the value that goes into the xxxx?

Comment: You can get the full join with `$ kubeadm token create --print-join-command` it will result to something like: `kubeadm join loadbalancer_host_name:port_that_is_listening --token <token string>     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx`.

If you want only the `sha256:xxxx` a small command using bash `$ openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -noout -pubkey | openssl rsa -pubin -outform DER 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f1` it will result to `xxxx`. Remember those commands need to be executed on one of the Master nodes.

Comment: Yep, thank you, went with the second option and works well.

Answer (score 0):

The command `kubeadm token create` does not have any flag `--control-plane`

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)

When you run the command `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` you get two commands in the output and you use the command with `--control-plane` flag to join the control plane node.

Comment: I do not get two outputs I only get one. :( Is it possible to have configured something wrong?

Comment: error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: could not find a JWS signature in the cluster-info ConfigMap for token ID "khs2bu"

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no separate token for adding more control plane, you just have to add `--control-plane` while adding.

To get the join command `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

Assuming certificates are already uploaded and set in place.
More details can be found here.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

Edit: sorry for delayed update
`kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key` can be used to create the key

then upload then using `kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs --certificate-key=<above key>`

and use this to create join command `kubeadm token create --print-join-command --certificate-key <key created above>`

You can pass `--control-plane` to above join command for additional control planes and ignore this flag for worker nodes

Comment: The stdout after launching the first node is: `kubeadm join nodeMaster:6443 --token xxxx --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx --control-plane --certificate-key xxxx`

My question is how do I generate these tokens (ca-cert-hash / certificate-key)?

I can find the directory on my master node (/etc/kubernetes/pki) but the keys are huge in comparison to the prime generated.

Comment: you can get it using `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

Comment: Unfortunately not :(. It only returns this for me :(

`kubeadm join loadBalancerIP:6443 --token 05odrq.712o9lv89kd4jg8x     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx`

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I am using self signed certificates, I have not yet pushed my certs (but it should not matter).

Comment: yes for above output, you can just add `--control-plane` to join more masters

Comment: Do you mean `kubeadm token create --print-join-command --control-plane`? There is no `--control-plane` for the command as in the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/).

Comment: sorry for delayed response

`kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key` can be used to create the key. then upload then using `kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs --certificate-key=<above key>`

and use this to create join command
`kubeadm token create --print-join-command --certificate-key <key created above>`

Answer (score -1):

I think you want the commands below.

Display the command:

```
echo "$(kubeadm token create --print-join-command) --control-plane"
kubeadm join 192.168.5.50:8443 --token b99yno.3ju18t22w80ishlz --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:8f16b6d5304f070de0d32a6663ffaa30ac58163f9cfd38be4af405ac78c93b73  --control-plane
```

Run the command:

```
echo "$(kubeadm token create --print-join-command) --control-plane"|sh
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Display the command" makes no sense. Did you mean "run the command?" Display means show.